# Background screen greyed out while using ActionButton

Tags: ios, swift, floating-action-button

I am using the third-party `ActionButton` to display a floating button in my Swift project. But when I click on that floating button(on the 'plus' sign), the main screen on which that floating button is loaded gets greyed out. It again becomes visible only after we have tapped again on the floating button (i.e. on the 'cross' button).

I don't want the background screen on which the floating button is loaded to be greyed out while I tap on the floating button and I want it to remain as it is. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: show your tried code with thirdparty button link also

Comment: The background getting greyed out is a default feature of that third-party (which can be maybe changed..but don't know how...) .

Comment: with out code or link we can't help you my bro

Comment: can you set button attribute txt property??

Comment: yes you are right...:) But for that I'll have to paste the whole class and that will be even confusing and maybe misleading too...:) But here is the link for that 3rd party . https://github.com/lourenco-marinho/ActionButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Enter Inside

ActionButton.swift

and comment this line, this  blurVisualEffect added to contentView

```
 self.contentView.addSubview(self.blurVisualEffect)
```

at this method

```
public init(attachedToView view: UIView, items: [ActionButtonItem]?) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Abdelahad Darwish.. It worked after that line was commented..Have given an upvote also...